# .htaccess redirect from subfolder to main folder

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect all URLs of type from

`www.domain.com/BE` (...and something behind)

to 
`www.domain.com`

How could I do this, knowing that www.domain.com/BE will now be used for www.domain.be ?

I have tried this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)www.domain.com/BE(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/  [R=301,L]
```

by putting it in the www.domain.com folder but it doesn't do what I want...

Thanks !

Any ideas :/ ?? I couldn't figure this out...

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^BE(?:/.*|)$ / [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Ok, when i do this i get 404 error page.
===>    The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: What is the URI that you tried? Can you also tell me matching line from your error.log?

Comment: It doesn't redirect to www.domain.com. It just stays at the same page searching for index.php

Comment: `The requested URL /index.php was not found` That just means that my suggested rule is working fine since it redirected `/BE/` to `/` and then Apache invokes `index.php` for `/` because of your `DirectoryIndex` directive.

Comment: i tried this : www.domain.com/BE/cart-details

error.log = script '/srv/d_dario/www/www.domain.com/htdocs/index.php' not found or unable to stat

Comment: If you check my code there is no mention of `index.php` anywhere :) So my guess is it can be either because of some other RewriteRule you have OR as I commented earlier because of your `DirectoryIndex`. Try changing your rule to `RewriteRule ^BE(?:/.*|)$ /foo.html [R=301,L,NC]` and see what happens.

Comment: ok but how does it come that it keeps the URL even if it's redirected ?

Comment: strange, by adding your last rule, it still redirects to index.php

Comment: that clearly tells me that either you haven't enabled mod_rewrite and .htaccess OR else you have some other conflicting code/.htaccess somewhere.

Comment: i do have .htaccess in the folder /BE as it is used for domain.be. I guess it's this one which disturbing :   
`RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ .*/index\.(php|html?)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ $1 [R=301,L]`